# .csv adding whitespace after a scan

Tags: java, css

I have a .dbf file and I put the link in the comment below. I need to scan in the contents of the file. I convert the file to a .csv and it scans in very nicely but seems to add one whitespace between each character. I tried replacing all whitespaces from one line with nothing (i.e.)

```
test.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

but this does not change anything. Funny thing is that if you intake from a .txt file, there are no added whitespaces but due to uneven delimeters I cannot intake this way.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Whitespaces not are only spaces (char 32)...**

Try this (but this removes ALL SPACE CHARS!!!!!!):

```
txt.replaceAll("\\p{javaSpaceChar}","")
```

If you get A B C D E:

```
txt.replaceAll("\\p{javaSpaceChar}(.{1})","$1")
```

This replaces all space chars before 1 char by the char.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`StringUtils.deleteWhitespace`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#deleteWhitespace%28java.lang.String%29) from Apache Commons Lang.

```
StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(test);
```

Comment: im trying to download the package. I uploaded the file though, could you test it to see if it works beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning test to equal to it's edited value?
So something like:

```
test = test.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Comment: Sorry I tested it and corrected myself, try inserting " " instead of "\\s"

Comment: that doesnt seem to work. did you test on the file I uploaded?